# Want to have one file up-loader to handle 3 methods in a view page (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am working on importing 3 types of format file named as excel, text and CSV in MVC. I have added 3 pages for importing 3 kinds of file. Now, I want to have one file up-loader and based on the file we select, it should go to the particular method to handle the operation. How can I achieve this? Help would be appreciated.

I would like to have all these 3 view page in single page and import the file whichever the format I select.

Update: I have a separate view for 3 file uploaders to upload file. For xls, I have a view and separate controller. Same for CSV format and Text. What I want now is, I would like to have one view instead of going to separate view to add xls/text/csv format files.

I have added view code for importing xls format to database.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ImportFromExcel", "Contact", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                                    {
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">

                <div class="control-label col-md-2">Excel:</div>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary" />

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
}

    View code for separate page ImportText:
View code of Text format:   

        @using (Html.BeginForm("ImportText", "Contact", FormMethod.Post,
                                            new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="control-label col-md-2">Excel:</div>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" class="" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? If you provide us with some code and we can help

Comment: what does 3 different pages means here 3 Views or 3 Controllers, add some code to highlight the issue?

Comment: Please have a look at updated code.

Answer (score 1):

if browser support it, you can use file api

check out working code of using file api on this jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/0GiS0/stn5F/

essentially you just get it like

```
var file = document.forms['formName']['inputName'].files[0];
var type = file.type;  // text/plain for example
if(type === "text/plain") {
    document.forms['formName'].action = "UploadForText"; // url for text
}
// etc
```